# Combining train + test data and running cross validation in R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have the following R code that runs a simple xgboost model on a set of training and test data with the intention of predicting a binary outcome.

We start by

1) Reading in the relevant libraries.

```
library(xgboost)
library(readr)
library(caret)
```

2) Cleaning up the training and test data

```
train.raw = read.csv("train_data", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
drop = c('column')
train.df = train.raw[, !(names(train.raw) %in% drop)]
train.df[,'outcome'] = as.factor(train.df[,'outcome'])


test.raw = read.csv("test_data", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
drop = c('column')
test.df = test.raw[, !(names(test.raw) %in% drop)]
test.df[,'outcome'] = as.factor(test.df[,'outcome'])

train.c1 = subset(train.df ,  outcome == 1)
train.c0 = subset(train.df ,  outcome == 0)
```

3) Running XGBoost on the properly formatted data.

```
train_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(train.df [,1:124]), label = train.raw[, "outcome"])
test_xgb = xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(test.df[,1:124]))
```

4) Running the model

```
model_xgb = xgboost(data = train_xgb, nrounds = 8, max_depth = 5, eta = .1, eval_metric = "logloss", objective = "binary:logistic", verbose = 5)
```

5) Making predicitions

```
pred_xgb <- predict(model_xgb, newdata = test_xgb)
```

My question is: How can I adjust this process so that I'm just pulling in / adjusting a single 'training' data set, and getting predictions on the hold-out sets of the cross-validated file?

Comment: try adding `nfold = 5` to do 5 fold CV to the `xgboost` call. Also you should specify more rounds, perhaps 1000 or so. If you do so `print_every_n = 100` is a welcome argument. In general if you specify the test set you will do validation if you specify nfold you will do k-fold CV.

Comment: @missuse Sorry I realized that my question wasn't that clear, your response is helpful though. Really what I'm looking to understand is how to make predictions on the holdout sets of a, say, 10 fold cross-validated data set containing only training data.

Comment: Sry I made a mistake, to specify k- fold CV, one needs to call `xgb.cv` function. here you can specify `prediction = TRUE` and you will have prediction for each fold: `model$pred` - they are in the same order as in your train set. Folds are specified in `model$folds`. Setting the seed prior xgb.cv will choose the same folds but not the same model, to reproduce the same model one needs to set `seed` inside the `xgb.cv` call.

Comment: @missuse Thanks, so would I simply replace xgboost with xgb.cv and add prediction = TRUE as an argument? Is there anything else I need to adjust for that to work?

Comment: Yes, `xgb.cv(nfold = 10, prediction = TRUE, seed = 123...)` else as in `xgboost` call

Comment: @missuse Thanks and so instead of using predict() at all I'd simply print model$pred or write the results of that to the relevant file?

Answer (score 1):

To specify k-fold CV in the xgboost call one needs to call `xgb.cv` with `nfold = some integer` argument, to save the predictions for each resample use `prediction = TRUE` argument. For instance:

```
xgboostModelCV <- xgb.cv(data = dtrain, 
                         nrounds =  1688,
                         nfold = 5,
                         objective = "binary:logistic",
                         eval_metric= "auc",
                         metrics = "auc",
                         verbose = 1,
                         print_every_n = 50,
                         stratified = T,
                         scale_pos_weight = 2
                         max_depth = 6, 
                         eta = 0.01, 
                         gamma=0,
                         colsample_bytree =  1 ,
                         min_child_weight = 1,
                         subsample=  0.5 ,
                         prediction = T)

xgboostModelCV$pred #contains predictions in the same order as in dtrain.
xgboostModelCV$folds #contains k-fold samples
```

Here's a decent function to pick hyperparams

```
function(train, seed){
  require(xgboost)
  ntrees=2000
  searchGridSubCol <- expand.grid(subsample = c(0.5, 0.75, 1), 
                                  colsample_bytree = c(0.6, 0.8, 1),
                                  gamma=c(0, 1, 2),
                                  eta=c(0.01, 0.03),
                                  max_depth=c(4,6,8,10))
  aucErrorsHyperparameters <- apply(searchGridSubCol, 1, function(parameterList){

    #Extract Parameters to test
    currentSubsampleRate <- parameterList[["subsample"]]
    currentColsampleRate <- parameterList[["colsample_bytree"]]
    currentGamma <- parameterList[["gamma"]]
    currentEta =parameterList[["eta"]]
    currentMaxDepth =parameterList[["max_depth"]]
    set.seed(seed)

    xgboostModelCV <- xgb.cv(data = train, 
                             nrounds = ntrees,
                             nfold = 5,
                             objective = "binary:logistic",
                             eval_metric= "auc",
                             metrics = "auc",
                             verbose = 1,
                             print_every_n = 50,
                             early_stopping_rounds = 200,
                             stratified = T,
                             scale_pos_weight=sum(all_data_nobad[index_no_bad,1]==0)/sum(all_data_nobad[index_no_bad,1]==1),
                             max_depth = currentMaxDepth, 
                             eta = currentEta, 
                             gamma=currentGamma,
                             colsample_bytree = currentColsampleRate,
                             min_child_weight = 1,
                             subsample=  currentSubsampleRate) 


    xvalidationScores <- as.data.frame(xgboostModelCV$evaluation_log)
    #Save rmse of the last iteration
    auc=xvalidationScores[xvalidationScores$iter==xgboostModelCV$best_iteration,c(1,4,5)]
    auc=cbind(auc, currentSubsampleRate, currentColsampleRate, currentGamma, currentEta,  currentMaxDepth)
    names(auc)=c("iter", "test.auc.mean", "test.auc.std", "subsample", "colsample", "gamma", "eta", "max.depth")
    print(auc)
    return(auc)
  })
  return(aucErrorsHyperparameters)
}
```

You can change the grid values and the params in the grid, as well as loss/evaluation metric. It is similar as provided by `caret` grid search, but `caret` does not provide the possibility to define `alpha`, `lambda`, `colsample_bylevel`, `num_parallel_tree`... hyper parameters in the grid search apart defining a custom function which I found cumbersome. `Caret` has the advantage of automatic preprocessing, automatic up/down sampling within CV etc.

setting the seed outside the xgb.cv call will pick the same folds for CV but not the same trees at each round so you will end up with a different model. Even if you set the seed inside the xgb.cv function call there is no guarantee you will end up with the same model but there's a much higher chance (depends on threads, type of model.. - I for one like the uncertainty and found it to have little impact on the result).

Comment: Thanks that function to pick hyperparams is especially useful. On a simpler note, right now I print to a table with something like `write.table(prob[, pred], "file")`, can I just do `write.table(xgboostModelCV$pred)` to the same effect?

Comment: Yes, try it, you can also construct a confusion matrix, ROC, lift curves, determine the probability threshold for the model (the `model$pred` for a two class problem contains in fact the probability of being a certain class). For these you will need to provide the true `label` as you did in  `xgb.DMatrix(data.matrix(train.df [,1:124]), label = train.raw[, "outcome"])`

Comment: Thanks so for example:

`write.table(myModel$pred[, c("name", "xgb")], "
file", 
sep = ",", 
row.names = FALSE, 
col.names = c("name", "outcome"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use xgb.cv and set prediction = TRUE.

Comment: Sorry can you elaborate on this?